# Scheduling the publication of Joomla Articles or Modules on certain dates and hours

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

How can I schedule Joomla Articles and Modules being published or unpublished on certain dates and hours? How can I repeat the publishing state hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly?

Example: I have 4 articles on my Joomla site.
- I want to publish the "Article 1" and the "Article 2" only on week days and unpublish them on weekends. 
- Also I want to publish the "Article 3" every day between 1:00 and 5:00 PM, and the "Article 4" publish it every Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Regular Labs Advanced Module Manager](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager/tutorial#default-settings) might help

With the pro version of the extension, you can publish / unpublish modules based on dates, times, and days of the week.

I can't think of an option to do the same for articles, but what if you had a few articles, with next to no content, just embedded modules? And these articles are always published.

Then you use the Regular Labs extension to manage the publishing and unpublishing of the modules on each page?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea but not a perfect solution and the it cost's money. 
For now I'll publish/unpublish the articles manually. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job using a joomla CLI application to set these for you.